# Adjust SimpleOnGestureListener.onFling() sensitivity

Tags: android, android-gesture

I have implemented SimpleOnGestureListener.onFling(), but I have to fling very fast to trigger it. Is there any way to make it more sensitive?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sensitivity or "oomph" needed to trigger an `onFling()` event is [checked here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/GestureDetector.java#559) in GestureDetector:

```
if ((Math.abs(velocityY) > mMinimumFlingVelocity)
        || (Math.abs(velocityX) > mMinimumFlingVelocity)){
    handled = mListener.onFling(mCurrentDownEvent, ev, velocityX, velocityY);
}
```

Sadly there is no existing method to change the private member `mMinimumFlingVelocity`. However you should be able to copy the entire GestureDetector class into a new class in your project and hard code a new value yourself.